# DBX Output Different When Using "." or "->"

Tags: c++, dbx

There's a function that's not working and I don't understand why, and DBX isn't helping. Below is what I'm talking about.

```
(dbx 12) print ((CCFundExpenseObject *)s1)->GetFundBranchGroup()
((class CCFundExpenseObject *) s1)->GetFundBranchGroup() = -2019
(dbx 13) print (*((CCFundExpenseObject *)s1)).GetFundBranchGroup()
(*((class CCFundExpenseObject *) s1)).GetFundBranchGroup() = 1
```

Logically, both lines should have the same result, right?

If you want more context, here's an explanation of the code:

- **GetFundBranchGroup()** returns a short stored in `CCFundExpenseObject`. That's it.
- **s1** is a `void*`

Comment: IMO, your *context* is adding to the confusion. How is it related to the print statements in the debugger you've shown above? And why all the `void *`s and casting; you're writing C++, not C! If `GetFundBranchGroup()` has side effects it is entirely possible for the first invocation to return `-2019` and the second `1`. There's not enough context here to answer your question.

Comment: No side effects; 'GetFundBranchGroup()' simply returns a short. And yes, 'void *' is more C, which probably says how long ago this code was written.